# 1960s coloring in manufacturing of fabric and plastic

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, plastic, engineering-history, product-design

I'm a art historian and would like to know why, in the 1960s, clothes and plastic products seem to have come in limited colours (e.g. white, yellow, red), whereas the 70s saw for instance orange, green, and more shades added to the assortment.
Is it because of chemical limitations, early on, in the coloring process during mamufacturing?
I need this info for a scholarly publication, so it would need to be citation worthy (i.e. no opinions).

Comment: `Is it because...?` is a question that asks for confirmation, yes/no ... it would make more sense to ask something like `what are the reasons?` instead

Comment: https://www.pigments.com/wp-content/uploads/ANTEC-2019-History-of-Colour-FINAL-Paper.pdf

Comment: [Green](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=green+plastic+1950s&iax=images&ia=images) & [orange](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=orange+plastic+1950s&iax=images&ia=images) plastic, glass & clothing existed in the 1950s & 1960s. They may have been limited in some markets & if so, possibly due to fashion of the time & place.

Comment: Also, please do not write comments as answers. Write them as comments & if you want to address a comment to a specific person place an @ before their user name.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess it is because of limitations in early production methods, but I could be wrong. Most internet sources suggest it is merely a question of fashion, though none give references to research. So confirmation from actual experts would already be valuable.
However, if there are other reasons, I would of course be happy to hear about them.

Comment: This probably should be part of the question.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tiger guy - I had found that article, Unfortunately it doesn't say anything about the transition from 60s to 70s.
But I'm looking into some of the bibliography for potential clues.

Comment: please fo not post answers  that are not answers ... please delete them ... you are not on a chat forum